# How to close a GNOME terminal tab from the keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I'm not talking about closing the terminal window itself which you can easily do by using the `exit` command. I'm talking about closing a tab that you have originally opened up by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> key combination. When I'm done working with it, I would like to close it down without lifting my hands up from the keyboard and going for the mouse to click that small X button. Is there a command for that?

[image]

Comment: Just exit the shell (ctrl-d)? The other tab will remain open.

Comment: So, I can use either exit or Ctrl+D to close a tab. Thank you.

Comment: A keyboard shortcut could actually be useful if you're trying to close a tab with a frozen unresponsive ssh session...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When the shell process inside the terminal tab exits, it will close. If it was the only tab, the entire window will close. So you just have to quit the Bash session.

Your Bash session quits...

- when you type the command `exit`.
- when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send an `EOT` ("End Of Transmission") code.
  Note that it must be pressed when the command prompt is empty, i.e. you haven't typed anything else on that line yet.

Please also note that you can nest multiple interactive shells. You can start a new shell inside the current one by running e.g. `bash`, `sh`, `python`, `bc`, ... The `exit` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will always only terminate the currently active shell, which is usually the innermost one.

Comment: another small addition: if you are inside more than 1 shell ... it will exit the shell and not close the tab.  (ie. "bash" "bash" "bash" requires 4 control-d's for the tab to close)

Comment: EOT, AKA EOF :D

Comment: @tac no, EOF is "End Of File". EOT is something else, although triggering EOT on a blank input line generates an EOF for the listening program. To learn more, I recommend you to read [this answer from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/4464570).

Comment: @ByteCommander I've never encountered a situation in which the difference is significant. EOF is to EOT as ETX is to SIGINT

Comment: @ByteCommander that SO answer isn't telling me more than I alrady know, sorry

Comment: Might be worth noting that Ctrl+u will clear the current line of the terminal so ctrl+u, ctrl+d will exit.

Answer (score 28):

From [the GNOME Terminal help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en#file-shortcuts):

- Close Tab: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>
- Close Window: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: Those are the defaults. See "Terminal" "preferences" "shortcuts" in case these do not work and "someone" changed them and forgot about the change. The other answers are ever so slightly flawed: exit or control-d only works on the 1st level (if you type "bash" you need 2 exits) and on an empty prompt.

Answer (score 8):

You already mentioned it, type exit and the tab (as well as the terminal session running within the tab) will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Like @YiboYang mentioned in comments, it is not possible to do `Ctrl + W` or `exit` in some cases:

> A keyboard shortcut could actually be useful if you're trying to close a tab with a frozen unresponsive ssh session.

That shorcut can be viewed/changed from the Menu bar, via File>Terminal>Preferences>Shortcuts

[GNOME terminal preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvzfo.png)

It is highlighted in the image above. Double-click on the **Shortcut key** and simple key-in a new combination to assign to it,

E.g. I have set mine as `Ctrl + W` to be synchronous with the standard browser shortcut to close a tab.